# Remove or disable save button from JasperViewer

Tags: java, jasper-reports

How can I remove the save button from JasperViewer? I found one way but it's from its JRViewer component, and I'm not convinced at all.

Comment: You have access to the source code, we took it apart and rebuilt as a custom viewer for our needs (better thread management for starters)

Answer (score 3):

```
private void adjustViewerLayoutAndLookAndShow(JasperViewer viewer) {
    Container contentPane = viewer.getContentPane();
    JRViewerToolbar toolbar = (JRViewerToolbar) ((JRViewer)((JPanel)contentPane.getComponents()[0]).getComponent(0)).getComponent(0);

    JButton btnSave = (JButton) toolbar.getComponent(0);
    btnSave.setEnabled(false);

    JButton btnPrint = (JButton) toolbar.getComponent(1);
    btnPrint.setEnabled(false);


    viewer.setTitle(extraInfo);
    viewer.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but I have stumbled here before I got it to work, so for the sake of future researchers I will show here what worked for me.

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;

public class MyJasperViewer extends JasperViewer {

    public MyJasperViewer(JasperPrint jasperPrint, boolean isExitOnClose) {
        super(jasperPrint, isExitOnClose);

        try {
            ((JPanel) this.viewer.getComponent(0)).remove(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

now use it like this

```
JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(url.openStream(), map, conn);

MyJasperViewer jv = new MyJasperViewer(jp, false);
jv.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Special thank for borj. and updated Codes of removing both save and print buttons.

```
public class CustomeJasperViewer extends JasperViewer {

    public CustomeJasperViewer(JasperPrint jasperPrint, boolean isExitOnClose) {
        super(jasperPrint, isExitOnClose);

        try {

            JPanel jPanel = ((JPanel) this.viewer.getComponent(0));

            Component btnSave = jPanel.getComponent(0);
            Component btnPrint = jPanel.getComponent(1);

            jPanel.remove(btnSave);
            jPanel.remove(btnSave);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void viewReport (){

    try {

        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(rep_path);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, rep_map, Connection);
        CustomeJasperViewer jv = new CustomeJasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
        jv.setVisible(true);

    } catch (JRException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

[image]